Typeahead.js with accents, dash etc
I'm using typeahead.js to auto-complete city names.
It is working, except when there is an accent (like "Mièges" the suggestion will stop at "Mie" if I do not put the "è" accent)
Same with dash "Maisons Laffites" doesn't work because in my database it's "Maisons-Laffites"
and same with this "ç" for example "Alencon" will not suggest anything, I need to type "Alençon".
Here is how I initialize typeahead:
$('#code_postal_ville').typeahead({
            minLength: 3,
            highlight: true,
        },
            {
                name: 'villes',
                source: function (query, syncResults, asyncResults) {
                    var tableName = 'villes_france_free';
                    console.log('Table Name:', tableName);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/get_cities.php',
                        method: 'GET',
                        data: { query: query, table: tableName }, 
                        dataType: 'json', 
                        success: function (data) {
                            var uniqueCities = new Set();
                            data.suggestions.forEach(function (item) {
                                if (item.toLowerCase().startsWith(query.toLowerCase())) {
                                    uniqueCities.add(item);
                                }
                            });

                            var filteredData = Array.from(uniqueCities);

                            asyncResults(filteredData);                         }
                    });
                }
            });

Am I missing an option or something ? I want the user to be able to not type a "ç" or "-" or accents like "éèàâ" etc... and still have a suggestion.
Thank you!
